# Make Dialog in landscape or portrait orintation

Tags: java, android

Hy,
i have got some trooubles in my dialog. If i want to use it on portrait orientation it behaves ok, but if its in landscape orinetation o can use only 4 seekbars.

[image: Portrait orientation]

[image: Landscape orientation]

Comment: That's because it obviously doesn't fit on the screen, from what I see in the screenshot(which is cut off). You'll need to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your entire layout in a `<ScrollView>`, it just gets truncated because the screen isn't 'high' enough. If you layout would be bigger in height, the first screen would be cut off too.